# non-sequential sublist in java

Tags: java, list, sublist

The List interface provides the method `List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`.

I am wondering if there is something already implemented in java to get a non-sequential sublist from a List, i.e. `List<E> subList(int[] indices)` that returns a view of the list at the prescribed indices.

I imagine that any changes to the subList (like set, remove, clear) would be reflected in the original list (although adding elements might not be supported).

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no method like that in Java SDK. You should create yours.

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible with mutability. Let's say the sublist indexes from the main list are {0,1,4} and the main list's indexes are {0,1,2,3,4}. What happens when {1} is removed from the mainList ? What if a new element is added between {1} and {4} in the subList; where does that belong on the mainList ? What about parallelism ?

Comment: The same problem happens with the subList method in the List interface; any structural changes to the original list make the sublist undefined. I'm assuming only changes are made to the sublist and that the add method is not supported in the sublist.

Comment: non-sequential sub list is not possible in list. You can implement like that.